# Set SiteDefinedSharingCapability property

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-administration, tenant

Does anyone know how to set the `SiteDefinedSharingCapability` property for a OneDrive site?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/site_name -SiteDefinedSharingCapability Disabled
```

The issue is that the parameter `SiteDefinedSharingCapability` does not exist in the `Set-SPOSite` commandlet.

At the same time, I can get the `SiteDefinedSharingCapability` property like so:

```
$site = Get-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/site_name
$site.SiteDefinedSharingCapability
```

**Update**

I have just found [an article by Mike Weaver that says](https://madmike.net/how-to-change-onedrive-for-business-sharing-policies-in-powershell-at-the-user-level/):

> Note:  Switch Behavior:  It should be noted that in PowerShell you do
> not change the "-SiteDefinedSharingCapability" switch.  If you change
> a user’s setting using the -SharingCapability switch, the
> "-SiteDefinedSharingCapability" will change to match the
> "-SharingCapability" setting.

Answer (score 0):

[An article by Mike Weaver that says](https://madmike.net/how-to-change-onedrive-for-business-sharing-policies-in-powershell-at-the-user-level/):

> Note: Switch Behavior: It should be noted that in PowerShell you do not change the "-SiteDefinedSharingCapability" switch.  If you change a user’s setting using the -SharingCapability switch, the "-SiteDefinedSharingCapability" will change to match the "-SharingCapability" setting.

As a result, the following command will update both `SiteDefinedSharingCapability` and `SharingCapability` properties.

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/my_site -SharingCapability Disabled
```